# VS 2010 command prompt default settings?

Tags: terminal, fonts, command-line, visual-studio-2010

I've got a problem with VS command prompt - it keeps using the wrong settings for fonts in the window. When I launch the command prompt via start -> run it works fine, when I launch my app directly via explorer, it works fine. But when I push the F5 button and compile my little app, the console that automatically starts via VS uses 4x4 raster fonts. No matter what the default settings are.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that create some app that waits for some input. And then go to the properties of that console, and change them. AFAIRemember, the changes will persist, and will work across other apps too.